# How can i auto restart pm2 server when db-migrate command run?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, pm2, dbmigrate

I am using the pm2 npm package and DB-migrate npm package. What I want -
**Either** 
when I migrate my DB so -

> db-migrate up , so pm2 restart 0 command also execute.

command auto execute to restart my server.

**Or**
I just run the pm2 start command. So

> db-migrate up command execute within this.

I don't want to run 2 commands in each migration.

Currently every time I need to do -

**db-migrate up**

**pm2 restart 0**

I want single command to migrate db and restart my Linux server